# Cannot get Unread emails from hotmail account using javamail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3, hotmail

I am trying to write a simple java program which returns me all the unread email from my hotmail account using javamail api. This is the code I am using :

```
        String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY); 
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.port", "995"); 
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3s.socketFactory.port", "995");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop3.live.com", username, password);
        System.out.println(store);

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        Message messages[] = inbox.search(ft);
```

What is my mistake in this code? Because I am getting all the mails instead of just the unread ones.

Comment: do you find any method like getUnread() of Inbox folder.

Comment: yes there is a method which can be called as inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from Sun's documentation about their bundled POP3 provider (which I'm assuming you are using) - the documentation is located in /docs/sundocs

> POP3 supports no permanent flags (see Folder.getPermanentFlags()). In
>   particular, the Flags.Flag.RECENT flag will never be set for POP3
>   messages. It's up to the application to determine which messages in a
>   POP3 mailbox are "new". There are several strategies to accomplish
>   this, depending on the needs of the application and the environment: A
>   simple approach would be to keep track of the newest message seen by
>   the application. An alternative would be to keep track of the UIDs
>   (see below) of all messages that have been seen. Another approach is
>   to download all messages into a local mailbox, so that all messages in
>   the POP3 mailbox are, by definition, new. All approaches will require
>   some permanent storage associated with the client.

I think that pretty much answers your question